# Post-apocalyptic sci-fi book about a Chinese migrant searching for her husband in a post-apocalyptic (possibly American) city

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

The story is about a migrant from China in a walled, post-apocalyptic city, possibly in America, searching for her husband, who may have been banished.

I think the book was published around 2013/2014 in hardback. Saw it on holiday in Moab, Utah, but couldn't afford the hardback, then forgot title and the author's name and have never found it again!

Comment: I removed the [tag:lost] tag since I don't think you meant to reference the show.

Comment: *Severance* (2018) is tantalizingly similar in theme, involving a Chinese migrant working in the United States during a fungal plague that has tumbled society, but no husband.

Comment: Any recollections of what was on the cover?